# How do I set my own global variables using input() in python 3.3?

Tags: function, web, python-3.x, global-variables

So I have been wondering something that I am sure has a very simple answer, yet I can't seem to wrap my head around it.  In a function, How do I set a global variable to perform a certain task.  For example, I tried:

```
def function():
    global x
    x = input("Name of variable: ")
    x = print("Working")
```

I also tried:

---

```
def function(Name_Of_Variable):
    global Name_Of_Variable
    Name_Of_Variable = print("Working")
```

---

Basically,  I just need to be able to set a global variable in a function.  The actual code that I am trying to get to work is this:

---

```
def htmlfrom(website_url):
    import urllib.request
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(website_url)
    variable_for_raw_data = (input("What will this data be saved as: "))
    global variable_for_raw_data
    variable_for_raw_data = response.read()
```

---

This is what happens:

```
>>> htmlfrom("http://www.google.com")
What will this data be saved as: g
>>> g
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    g
NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```

---

Things to keep in mind:

- Python 3.3
- GLOBAL variables (not local)

Comment: I'm genuinely curious as to which Python tutorial is telling you to use global variables...

Comment: Have you tried approaching the problem in another way which would not require a global variable?

Comment: I haven't followed a python tutorial on this.  To the best of my understanding, a global variable is just one that can be accessed anywhere.  Why wouldn't they be useful, or is there a more useful method?  Please elaborate.  No I have not tried in another way.  Is there one?

Comment: It is generally better to pass variables amongst functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments: as far as I can tell there is NO need for a global variable. (I'd be happy to be convinced to the contrary if that's really what you think you need.)

A more modular way to program is to `return` the variable, thus allowing you to pass data between functions. E.g.:

```
import urllib.request # `import` statements at the top! have a look at PEP 8

def htmlfrom(website_url):
    ''' reads HTML from a website 
        arg: `website_url` is the URL you wish to read '''
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(website_url)
    return response.read()
```

---

Then let's say you want to run this function for multiple websites. Instead of creating a variable for each website, you can store the HTML in a `dict` or `list` or other data-structure. E.g:

```
websites_to_read = ('http://example.com',
                    'http://example.org',)

mapping_of_sites_to_html = {} # create the `dict`

for website_url in websites_to_read:
    mapping_of_sites_to_html[website_url] = htmlfrom(website_url)
```

Comment: Maybe there is no need for global variable in the FIRST function, but what about when I want html from multiple websites?  That is why I need more than one variable, right?

Comment: You don't need more than one variable. Instead please consider storing the HTML of multiple sites in a `dict`, `list` or other data-structure.

Comment: How would the code look with a dictionary?  I don't know how I would store them with different variables in a dictionary.